# Sequelize Instance.destroy(...) does not return any information if rows has been deleted or not

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, delete-row

May be related to this open issue: [instance.destroy(...) does not return any information if rows has been deleted or not](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4124) but that seems to be more related to `Model.destroy(...)` which according to [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-destroy) should return the number of rows deleted.

I am new to Sequelize so please correct me if I am doing something wrong. I am using it with MySQL 8.0.16 and running sequelize 5.21.2

When using `Model.findAll(...)` and then looping through the rows and processing a `Instance.destroy()` I am being returned the instance per the [`Instance.destroy(...)` documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-destroy)

```
db.tags.findAll({where: MyWhereObj, attributes: MyFieldArray}).then(tags => {
  _.forEach(tags, tag => {
    //more processing scripts for tag
    tag.destroy().then(deleted => {
      console.log(deleted)
    })
  })
})
```

What I would like to know is if the row was successfully deleted. I browsed through the returned instance looking if such an attribute like `isNewRecord` existed for `isDeletedRecord` but no similar

I can watch the node console and see the query come through correctly. Is it safe and best practice to assume the row was deleted successfully?

The query is sent to MySQL as...

```
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `guid` = 'aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd'
```

...which should the number of rows deleted, but Sequelize seems to ignore that information

I am thinking that I can catch a deletion error or a retrieving/processing error using these catch blocks. But wondering if there is a better way to simply know if the deletion took place or not

```
db.tags.findAll({where: MyWhereObj, attributes: MyFieldArray}).then(tags => {
  _.forEach(tags, tag => {
    // more processing scripts for tag
    tag.destroy().then(deleted => {
      console.log(deleted)
    }).catch(err =>{
      // The row was not deleted
      console.error(err)
    })
  })
}).catch(err => {
  // Error in Retrieving/Processing
  console.error(err)
})
```

Comment: Open issue :) https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4124

Comment: Yes, that is what I linked to, but that issue is more related to Models instead of instances as the Model docs state that they should return a promise with the number of rows deleted.

Comment: I'm using sequelize too, in a project and I'm thinking going full revert and using another library. If you can too, please do it. I even noticed that, if you want to use hooks + on cascade delete, you have to use the INSTANCE DESTROY... otherwise the MODEL DESTROY doesn't fire the cascade on delete nor before / after destroy hook.

Use another library if you can, there are many many bugs 5 years old still open.

Comment: Well, I am already committed and mostly done with that part. I used sequelize in graphQL API and then use the graphQL API in the react front end.

Comment: I finally came to the conclusion to just assume it was deleted. I am not using any foreign keys on the tables, so there is not much to prevent a delete other than if it was not found to delete or the connection died. If it does not exist then I don't really need to worry about it and if the connection dropped then I have a world of other problems that will throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are two destroy methods:

[https://sequelize.org/v6/class/src/model.js~Model.html#static-method-destroy](https://sequelize.org/v6/class/src/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-destroy)
and
[https://sequelize.org/v6/class/src/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-destroy](https://sequelize.org/v6/class/src/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-destroy)

The v6 documentation says the static method returns `Promise<number>`, and the instance method returns a `Promise` (it does not specify what type the promise resolves to).

Also note that some methods return a different type for different dialects. For example, the model static method decrement documents its return value as:

`Promise<Model[], ?number>   returns an array of affected rows and affected count with options.returning true, whenever supported by dialect`

Using sqlite dialect, I have found the destroy instance method to return a promise to the deleted model, not a promise to the deleted row count.

I think the documentation is incorrect, and (to answer your question), I don't think there is a simple way to confirm success of the deletion. I tried this:

```
  const alloc = {code to get the model}
  const alloc2 = alloc;
  const deletedRowsCount = await alloc.destroy();
  const destroy2Result = await alloc2.destroy();
```

and the when I logged the results with `console.log({ deletedRowsCount, destroy2Result })`, I got the exact same output for both destroys:

```
{
  deletedRowsCount: allocs {
    dataValues: {
      id: 2,
      amount: null,
      locked: false,
      createdAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      genLedgerAcctId: 9,
      tranId: 1
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 2,
      amount: null,
      locked: false,
      createdAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      genLedgerAcctId: 9,
      tranId: 1
    },
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  destroy2Result: allocs {
    dataValues: {
      id: 2,
      amount: null,
      locked: false,
      createdAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      genLedgerAcctId: 9,
      tranId: 1
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 2,
      amount: null,
      locked: false,
      createdAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-02-26T20:35:46.139Z,
      genLedgerAcctId: 9,
      tranId: 1
    },
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
}
```

I plan to update this answer for other database types, in particular when I use a dialect that support foreign keys, so I can have a destroy that DOES fail.